# What shall I use for full text search and fuzzy search on a social network django site with a postgresql database?

Tags: django, postgresql, elasticsearch, sphinx, fuzzy-search

So, I was looking for a search engine for my new django project with a postgresql database and I ended up with elasticsearch and sphinx. I've chosen the second one, because I thought that if you're searching in a lot of posts you need a fast search, which uses less memory, but after looking at realization of sphinx I went up like, "How do I do that on python and can I do fuzzy search with it?". I've found few django-sphinx libraries, but they seem to be abandoned (last update was 5 years ago), and in sphinx documentation I didn't find anything about django, just few mentions of python. So, is sphinx still alive and how can I use it with django, or should I choose another engine for my tasks?

Comment: you can use postgresql with gin index , in general it scales well and easy to maintain if you are already familiar with postgresql - use this blog to learn the basics - Inverted Index Gin in use in Postgresql - http://hello-worlds.in/2021/05/11/understanding-postgresql-indexes-for-beginners-part-4-gin/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Postgres as the database, you can take a look at [Postgres FullText search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/textsearch.html), it might suit your need.

Django has support for it, here's the [official documentation.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/)

Comment: Yeah, but what if database is going to be highly loaded by big amount of users being online and some of them will try to search something at the same time? I guess this will lead to database's overload(or will just worsen performance of database), so that's why I don't consider the postgresql's search. But maybe I'm wrong with that, I don't know.

Comment: This is kinda why this sort of 'subjective' question doesnt work on stackoverflow. We dont know either. A lot of choosing a particular product is personal preference, and depends on your specific circumstances. In this example, some sites might cope just fine with the the built in search, but other heavier busier sites, might be better 'offloading' the search to a seperate service. Picking a solution might just come down to testing a few, and seeing which works best!